# Post content not showing in the edit post textarea. (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I’m currently building a plugin which requires me to remove the TinyMCE editor and replace with a text area.

The following code helps me to remove the TinyMCE editor from the admin area:

```
function wpdocs_remove_post_type_support() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
}

add_action('init' ,'wpdocs_remove_post_type_support' );
```

Then I add my own textarea with the following code:

```
function myprefix_edit_form_advanced() {


require('texteditor.html'); 

}   

add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_advanced' );
```

My texteditor.html looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body> 

<div> 
 <textarea id="text" name="post_content" data-placeholder="start writing...">


 </textarea>

  </div> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

After all the above code, I was able to save content using the textarea but when I got to the edit post area, no post content is showing up in the textarea field. My question is, is there any function I can call to make sure the post content shows up in the textarea.

I’d really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all your code and replace with:

```
function replace_tinymce_by_textarea( $settings, $editor_id ) {
if ( $editor_id == 'content' ) {
    $settings['tinymce']   = false;
    $settings['quicktags'] = false;
    $settings['media_buttons'] = false;
}
return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'replace_tinymce_by_textarea', 10, 2 );
```